# Create Multiple Calculated columns using one DAX formula

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is it possible to create 2 different columns using one DAX Expression?

I have 2 column, for example **Work Done this month** and **Invoiced Amount**. I want to create 2 columns using these.

1. Work Done - Invoiced and return only positive values (**Deferred**)
2. Invoiced - Work Done and return only positive values (**Extra**)

**Note**: I know how to add these columns using 2 DAX formula's here, but I would like to know if its possible with one formula.

Samsple Screenshot below:
[image: Sample Screenshot]

Comment: Calculated Columns? No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is possible but not within the existing table and it strongly depends on the context on which your are calculating. When your calculation is performed on a row level, ADDCOLUMNS could help you out. It allows you to create a new table and add multiple calculated columns.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/addcolumns-function-dax

Comment: Looks like this is the only way currently. Thank you. But I think this takes a lot of processing as compared to adding 2 Calculated columns. Is that correct?